# How long does initial replication take in DFS?

Tags: windows-server-2008, replication

I have two windows servers, one 2008 SP2 R1 ( x86 ), and the other 2008 R2 running a 2008 DFS namespace, and replicating between the two.

I have approximately 600GB of data being replicated over a 1Gbps LAN.

I set replication up almost a week ago, but the server is still telling me that the initial replication is not complete for that vast majority of the folders I have under my DFS root.

I only have about 30 folders, and so far I have only seen on show initial replication complete.

I can see that the two systems are out of sync.

How long does this take? 
If this is too long, which I suspect it is, how can I begin to run down the problem keeping replication from running properly?

Comment: might be to late but you could have prestaged the data.
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947726

Comment: Also are these on the same subnet?  Are the nics setup correctly, should be auto/auto if not then its a gamble..  Is the source server still having a lot of modifications done to it?

Comment: I did an initial copy by hand using robocopy before setting up the replication.

Comment: unfortuantely the robocopy screws up the replication information so that it will redo the entire copy.

Comment: @tony - good to know. What is recomended then? xcopy?

Comment: if you follow the link I sent they'll explain things. In other words you'll need to use windows backup!

Comment: Yet another good reason to read before responding.

Comment: But... hasn't Windows Backup been depreciated from Windows 2008? It's got an image backup but can you restore files to another server?

Comment: Also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc773238(WS.10).aspx infers you can seed by simplying copying the files. I suspect in this case, it might go through the motions of copying each file but the differential copy feature means that it doesn't actually copy the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it depends. On latency and bandwidth. With a 600gb load and a 1gb link I would say a day or two maximum.

Any other information? Logs, errors? There are various issues that can lead to a slow / non replicating behavior if staging gets filled up. A week would still be more than I would accept on a 1gb LAN, though.